# Adding exceptions for not recognized error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, paramiko

I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 286, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

When I enter wrong hostname. I want to put an exception, giving message that wrong hostname was entered, but Python does not recognize that error and I get global name gaierror not defined.

I was trying like this:

```
try:
    ssh.connect(rec.host, username=rec.user, password=rec.password)
except gaierror:
    print 'blablabla'
```

Then it gives this error:

```
    except gaierror:
NameError: global name 'gaierror' is not defined
```

Do I need to define that error myself somehow or I need to call something from `paramiko`, so python would understand that exception?

Comment: How do you know a host is wrong?

Comment: Because I entered not existing host (on purpose ofc)?.. And when it does not find such host, it throws that `gaierror`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the `gaierror` exception from the `socket` module. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gaierror)

```
import socket

try:
    # Your code.
except socket.gaierror:
    # Handle exception.
```